# How to pass api values starting with "on" in LWCs to create form abstractions?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

In modern JS development ecosystems, we have form abstraction libraries to aid in creating of forms with rich interactivity.

In my app, I attempted to do something like this:

```js
export default class formWrapper extends LightningElement {
  @api onSubmit;
  @api onChange;
}
```

With the usage being something like (in a separate component using the above custom component)

```html
<c-form-wrapper onSubmit={myOnSubmit} />
```

This raises the error:

> Invalid property name "onSubmit". Properties starting with "on" are reserved for event handlers.

I wish LWCs didn't impose artificial limitations on api names but I'm not surprised either given their other limitations.

Do you have a suggestion for a pattern that lets me pass through arbitrary API names, to make a form wrapper easier to use?

**I don't want to pass in manually prefixed names like `<c-form-wrapper onFormWrapperSubmit={myOnSubmit} />`** because this makes the component more awkward to use.

Comment: When you use `<c-form-wrapper onsubmit={myOnSubmit} />`, presumably `myOnSubmit` is an event handler function, right?  In that case, you aren't going to define `onsubmit` as a variable, you're going to be dispatching `submit` events.  See docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch

Comment: I'd like to see a full example of this design. Assumedly, you'd need a default `onSubmit` or `onChange` event handler to use in case it's not overridden, right? Or maybe you can use `this.template.addEventListener` to [dynamically add listeners](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_handling) as needed.